# Which site for making decisions about hardware

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which site can I use for making decisions about hardware? Like, for example, asking about which hardware would be better to use, depending on the circumstances.

I saw [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com), but I am not sure if I am allowed to ask about deciding which product to use, when I already have the respective products. I do not think that would make sense, because: by:
https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

> a request for information that will lead to a product decision

I think, that it means, that I should expect to get answers giving more information about the decision. But, I expect a site for asking which product would be better to use, why, and what are the consequences of each.

Example question on [hardware recommendations (10K only)](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14494/my-ssd-vs-my-hdd-for-server-help-me-decide), where I want to know which product would be better to use for my server, and I have also narrowed the question as much as possible, so the answers wouldn't be opinion based.

Comment: In general, it's easier to advise which site might be best if you say specifically what question you're proposing to ask.

Comment: Given that you've [already asked it](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14494), you should really be able to include the actual question.

Comment: I would've recommended Hardware Recommendations, but you've already asked your question there ;)

Comment: Why does that matter? Only people with the appropriate rep can view it anyway, and you should have included it to start with so people could tell you if and where it did belong on this network.

Comment: Surely that makes it even _less_ relevant to you whether or not it's linked? That's still a relevant link for this question, because it's the actual question you're asking about.

Answer (score 2):

[Super User](https://superuser.com/) might be a good fit here:

> Super User is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about computer software or **hardware**.

Comment: The into on the tour page explicitly allows hardware questions.